# how to login once and stay logged in until you log out?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I couldn't  figure it out. as i restart the app (if i am signed in or not) it goes to the login page, can you guys help me out on this. i am new to flutter so detailed instructions will be appreciated. Thanks

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: (googleSignIn.isSignedIn() != null) ? MainPage() : LoginPage(),
    routes: {
      'upload': (context) => ItemInput(),
      'toyota': (context) => Toyota(),
    },
  ));
}
```

Auth.dart

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAcount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAcount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

  final UserCredential authResult =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);
  return user;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

Login.dart

```
void click() {
    signInWithGoogle().then((user) => {
          this.user = user,
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()))
        });
  }

RaisedButton.icon(
                  
                  onPressed: () async {
                    click();
                  },
                  
                  label: Text(
                    'Sign-up with Google     ',
                  )),
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically restores the user's authentication state when the app is restarted. So you'd typically detect whether the user is already signed in, and then navigate to the post-login screen when they are.

According to the documentation on [authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) you can get the authentication state with:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
      // ... navigate to post-login screen
    }
  });
```

Comment: but i cant Navigate inside that

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using `shared preference`, see, https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

When the signin is successful do,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
```

This will store a boolean value that you use to check if the user is signed in or not. It will be saved even after the app is closed unless you uninstall or clear app data.

and in the `main.dart` use that stored prefs value to check if the user is already signed in or not by doing -

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn");
```

Use the isLoggedIn value, navigate the user to either Login Screen or Home Screen, and use it to perform other logic.